# Web Server Security Strategy

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machines, security, mysql

I was hacked yesterday and so I've been thinking all day how I could make my system secure.

I'm thinking of doing setting up a hypervisor that runs a few VM's.

The architecture I have in mind is this:

- MySQL VM - NO INTERNET. Runs only MySQL server, and a HTTP server with an exposed endpoint for API calls. Does NOT have internet access. The HTTP server is for internal calls between the site webserver and the MySQL webserver, and this the database credentials do not need to be exposed.
- Site Web Server VM - WITH INTERNET. Runs only the web server, on Linux, has internet access (obviously) and restrict so the OS only allows only 1 process to execute, and that is the Web Server process (written in NodeJS).
  This web server communicates with the MySQL webserver in order to do insert, update and get from database.
- Files VM - NO INTERNET. Hosts relevant server scripts over SMB. One folder will only allow read, not write. Another folder will host files uploaded by users, this folder is both read and write.
  Yet another folder will host files generated by the Processing VM (read below), which is read only.
- Processing VM - NO INTERNET. This VM will process user uploads, and when done, move the files to a folder in the Files VM.

Is this a reasonable way to protect my server?

Comment: I'd like to take a minute and ask you, how exactly you've been hacked? "Hacked" is a very broad term, so your system might be secure and you might have some issue unrelated to software security.

Comment: @almarcDudeas How? I have no idea. What happened? Woke up to a user asking me if the site was down, and upon investigation, I was presented with a ransomware. More info here: https://superuser.com/questions/1540755/how-was-my-server-infected?noredirect=1#comment2340290_1540755

Comment: More VMs, more chances to get one wrong and hackable. There is nothing you can do to protect each of these that you can't do to protect a single one. And as long as you don't know how you were hacked you will have four problems instead of one. And you web server likely needs to be able to spawn processes...

Comment: Please explain how the VM's not connected to the internet can be hacked. I am curious of if I'm missing something.

Comment: @vaid it is on a machine which is connected to internet, it talks to other VMs that are   connected to the internet, so it is potentially connected to the internet. Never be too certain.

Comment: @xenoid Nope. The physical machine is connected to mobile internet, which internet is activated by an SMS message. The Web Server VM is connected to the internet using its own physical network interface. The other VM's are on the same physical machine as the Web Server VM, but none of them have internet access. just extremely restricted internal networking. I'm trying to eliminate as many points of access as possible.